# Autofac: Register services that are related to each other and resolve with name/key/meta/index

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a situation with autofac registration where services are related to each other. Here's what I have now:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

const string A = "A";
const string B = "B";

//Part 1
builder.RegisterType<ClassA1>().Named<IClass1>(A);
builder.RegisterType<ClassA2>().Named<IClass2>(A);

builder.RegisterType<ClassB1>().Named<IClass1>(B);
builder.RegisterType<ClassB2>().Named<IClass2>(B);

//Part 2
builder.Register(c => new ClassProcess(A, c.ResolveNamed<IClass1>(A), c.ResolveNamed<IClass2>(A))).Named<ClassProcess>(A).SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new ClassProcess(B, c.ResolveNamed<IClass1>(B), c.ResolveNamed<IClass2>(B))).Named<ClassProcess>(B).SingleInstance();

//Part 3
builder.Register(c => new ClassProcessDependency(c.ResolveNamed<ClassProcess>(B), c.ResolveNamed<ClassProcess>(A)));
```

In Part 1 I define the two basic classes that are connected in pairs, IClass1 and IClass2.

In Part 2 I define a "process" that connects these two classes. This process is what's actually passed on to the rest of the program, which takes an IEnumerable.

In Part 3 I define any dependencies that exists between these processes so that they are executed in correct order.

What I'm looking for here is some register method in Autofac that can use services that have been previously registered with name/key/meta and use that data for registering new services.

Edit: Please note that I'm trying to find out if there is any Autofac-specific way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your constants in a list you can enumerate through...

```
IEnumerable<string> constants
```

...is there a reason you couldn't do this?

```
foreach(var constant in constants)
{
  // Careful of the closure...
  var loopItem = constant;
  builder
    .Register(c =>
      new ClassProcess(
        loopItem,
        c.ResolveNamed<IClass1>(loopItem),
        c.ResolveNamed<IClass2>(loopItem)))
    .Named<ClassProcess>(loopItem)
    .SingleInstance();
}
```

Unless I'm mistaken or misunderstanding, the only thing holding you back would be if the set of identifier constants isn't in a list already, which isn't something Autofac can help you with.

If you don't like having that foreach right in your code, you can always hide it in a module:

```
public class ProcessModule : Autofac.Module
{
  private IEnumerable<string> _constants;
  public ProcessModule(IEnumerable<string> constants)
  {
    this._constants = constants;
  }

  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    // Put the foreach here and loop over this._constants.
  }
}
```

Then register the module in your main code:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new ProcessModule(constants));
```

**If you aren't able to loop like that, then you may be limited in your automation approach.** Or, at least, you'll be looking at something a lot more... *complex*.

The `ContainerBuilder` doesn't really allow direct access to the set of registered items while they're being registered so you have to do a bit more low-level trickery. You could probably implement an `IRegistrationSource` to locate all named registrations of a certain type and do the automation.

**Unfortunately, this process, as mentioned, is a bit more complex, so I'm not going to write out a whole solution.** I'll tell you basically what I think would work, though, and give you some references to go look in the source code for examples.

**Before you start down this road**, [Nick Blumhardt has a nice article on his blog](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/) that explains how to write one of these and uses one of the built-in Autofac sources as the example.

First, you need to **implement an `Autofac.Core.IRegistrationSource`.** This is the interface that is used to do things like add implicit collection support (so if you register five `IFoo` instances you can resolve `IEnumerable<IFoo>` and it works). You can look at examples of registration sources in the Autofac code in the core Autofac assembly:

- [Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs)
- [Autofac.Features.GeneratedFactories.GeneratedFactoryRegistrationSource](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac/Features/GeneratedFactories/GeneratedFactoryRegistrationSource.cs)
- [Autofac.Features.LazyDependencies.LazyWithMetadataRegistrationSource](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac/Features/LazyDependencies/LazyWithMetadataRegistrationSource.cs)

The primary function in a registration source is the `RegistrationsFor` method, which returns the list of registrations generated by your source:

```
IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
  Service service,
  Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor);
```

Your implementation of this method will check to see if the incoming `service` is...

- An `Autofac.Core.KeyedService` (because you're naming all of your services) AND
- Of the type you expect.

If all of the planets align, you return an `IComponentRegistration` for your `ClassProcess` with all the settings filled out.

Now, this is going to be made more difficult because your `ClassProcess` requires TWO input parameters that are named and you probably don't want to register the named `ClassProcess` unless you're sure all the parameter dependencies are also registered, so you'll have to keep track of which services you've seen and only register the `ClassProcess` once you've seen all of the dependencies for it come in. (You can use the `KeyedService` coming in to figure out what the name of the service is.)

Further, you're not working with `ContainerBuilder` to create that component registration anymore, so you'll have to figure out all the right settings on the registration that correspond with things like "lifetime scope" and so on.

**Once you have your `IRegistrationSource` you need to hook it up to the `ContainerBuilder`.**

```
builder.RegisterSource(new MyRegistrationSource());
```

Again, I'd check out those source files in the Autofac tree if you're interested in pursuing this. It's not a road many people go down due to the complexity.

Honestly... **if you can just loop through the constants, I'd do that**. This seems like a lot of work to go through just to avoid a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You're right that looping through the constants specifically is a solution. However, what I was hoping for was an Autofac-way to do this, something that could register all services that had been registered with a name in one go, *and* use that name. I'm sorry for not being specific enough, I'll update my question.

Comment: I updated my answer to include information on an "Autofac Way" of automating it, but it's not easy. If you're looking for both "easy" and "automated," I am not sure you're going to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer and I read it before, I simply forgot to mark it as accepted, sorry!